# How to edit the search result in Google?

Tags: php, html, search, seo, search-engine

[image]

Take yahoo as example,

how to control the following? (to make it simple, the result apply to the all countries)

1. title
2. description
3. can select which six page to show in search result?
4. six sub-title and their short description

Studied a while and found that the result are auto detect , so how to manually change them and how to make sure the changes since it take some time before the new search result is take effect?

http://support.aarcade.net/how-do-i-update-or-change-the-google-search-results-for-my-site/

thanks a lot

Comment: sorry for too board, would you mind provide some guideline for start with e.g. how to change the title e.g. from header meta , robot.txt etc...?

Comment: e.g. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title for each page including sitelinks (those six pages underneath) is from `<title>` tag in the page `<head>`.
Same goes for Description, those are from `<description>` tag.

Keep in mind that Google can alter or change them completely based on the page content and title/description provided.

4. You can't choose witch sitelinks to include, Google choses them automatically. But you can demote them with Webmaster Tools.

Comment: thanks, can I specific the language use in search result, e.g. title for french , title for english , title for germany in header?

Comment: You can specify page language. Simplest way is to provide _lang_ attribute to _html_ tag `<html lang="en">` But Google will try to determine that automatically. Of course you must have unique page for each page/language.

Comment: that means I need to demote all the links? around 500 links to have that 6 site links specific?

Comment: No you should let Google decide which sitelinks to display. Demote only those links that you absolutely don't want to show up in results, like 404 page in case it shows up.

Comment: You should only worry about providing good content, relevant Title and Description. There are other things that would improve overall search results, like sitemaps, hreflang, structured data, image names, etc.